# Magento: Get country that user has chosen

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I have a piece of code which creates dropdown list of the countries

```
<div class="input-box">
   <?php $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadData()->toOptionArray(false) ?>
   <?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?>
      <select name="country" id="country" onchange="print()">
         <option value=""> </option>
         <?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $_country['label'] ?>
                </option>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to get the country which user has chosen. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="input-box">
<?php $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadData()->toOptionArray(false) ?>
<?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?>
  <select name="country" id="country" onchange="showCountry(this)">
     <option value=""> </option>
        <option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>" <?php echo $select; ?> >
            <?php echo $_country['label'] ?>
        </option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>       </select>
 <?php endif; ?>
</div>

function showCountry​(ele){
  alert(ele.value);
}  ​
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but nothing changes when I choose the country.

Comment: do you need country when combobox changed?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know what country has been chosen by user from drop down menu. So I can print it, change laguage, redirect user to specific page or type some warnings.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use the selected value in php?

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer, you can add selected country value to hidden variable and get it via php otherwise use ajax or jquery.

Comment: save showCountry(this) value into magento session so you can use it in any page